# How to load a usercontrol on initialization

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

How do I load a usercontrol on initialization? I have a usercontrol in my build which is in the folder appPages. The user control is called FindMe.

I tryed:

```
public MainWindow()
{         
InitializeComponent();
PanelMainContent.Children.Add(UserControl(appPages.FindMe));
```

But my syntax is wrong as usercontrol is a type but it says its being used like a variable.. :S

Comment: @SLaks Nothing my syntax is wrong, UserControl is a type but used like a variable. I just dont know how to call my usercontrol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to instantiate your control:

```
PanelMainContent.Children.Add(new appPages.FindMe());
```

or, if your control is named `UserControl` and appPages.FineMe is a static property?:

```
PanelMainContent.Children.Add(new UserControl(appPages.FindMe));
```

At least that is what it sounds like. Whatever your control name is, you have to `new` it up and that is what you `Add` to the `Children` of `PanelMainContent`